# print statement is changing code behavior : python

Tags: python

This is my code snippet

```
if( start_city == end_city ):
    is_rnd_trip = 1

    for i in range(1,len(keylist)):
        prev_leg = parse(d[keylist[i-1]][5])
        current_leg = parse(d[keylist[i]][4])
        delta = relativedelta(current_leg, prev_leg)
        print
        print delta
        if(delta > max_delta):
            max_delta = delta
            print max_delta
            indx_of_max_delta = i

    end_city = d[keylist[indx_of_max_delta]][1]

print '\nindx_of_max_delta: ',indx_of_max_delta
print start_city,end_city
```

Output:

```
relativedelta(hours=+18, minutes=+10)
relativedelta(hours=+18, minutes=+10)

relativedelta(days=+10, hours=+15, minutes=+45)
relativedelta(days=+10, hours=+15, minutes=+45)

relativedelta(hours=+20, minutes=+50)

indx_of_max_delta:  2
SEA BLR
```

However if I comment out the print lines I get a different output. I have no idea what is going wrong. The output I am getting before I comment out the print lines is correct and is what I expect. I am using Spyder editor (if that helps )

```
if( start_city == end_city ):
    is_rnd_trip = 1

    for i in range(1,len(keylist)):
        prev_leg = parse(d[keylist[i-1]][5])
        current_leg = parse(d[keylist[i]][4])
        delta = relativedelta(current_leg, prev_leg)
        print
        #print delta
        if(delta > max_delta):
            max_delta = delta
            #print max_delta
            indx_of_max_delta = i

    end_city = d[keylist[indx_of_max_delta]][1]

print '\nindx_of_max_delta: ',indx_of_max_delta
print start_city,end_city
```

Output

```
indx_of_max_delta:  3
SEA DXB
```

Comment: can you provide a self-contained code snippet (which we can execute) that reproduces the error?

Comment: Make sure you aren't mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: @wheaties, an empty print statement just prints a blank line

Answer (score 0):

In Python, an *iterator* is like a list, but it's just a stream of data.  Once it streams through your program it's gone.  It's very efficient, but can be confusing to use, as you've found out.

I suggest converting it into a list, so you can print it out and process it:

```
delta = list( relativedelta(current_leg, prev_leg) )
```